# Blender forces computer to reboot after mistyping extreme value for resolution icosphere

Tags: interface, edit-mode

After that I added an icosphere and wanted to change the resolution from 2 to 5, I stupidly mistyped the 5 to 45, so Blender freezes up and forced my computer to reboot. I didn't save the file so I had to redo a lot. Is it possible that Blender saves the file or makes a notification, when it sees that the input value is too much, before executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed as [rB60575480](https://developer.blender.org/rB60575480583500f27698e2e3e372ec8fab40033e) (now max possible value is **10** here, which already means 2.6M vertices…).

But please next time report such issues on [our bug tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug).

Comment: @mont29 I just set blender to subdivide a cube 10,000 times and my computer crashed. Should that be reported too? Does it not depend on what hardware people are running as to whether it will crash the computer?

Comment: @Ray Mairlot yep, such things should be reported. It does depends on peoples' hardware, but not much actually - maybe a factor ten between most (common) weak and o we can define common sane max values in such cases (user can always subdiv twice e.g. if they really need a one trillion vertices sphere :P ).

Comment: Ok, I'll put a report in.